# r and (r-1) complements

Tags: digital-logic

i have learned that usage of complements simplifies the subtraction operation and is used for logical manipulation....

But , I really don't seem to get it?? how does it simplifies our calculation ?? and why do we even have to find the 9's and 10's complement for decimal number??

I have searched it , but every where it just says its used to simplify stuff and then give the method of finding them respectively....i do understand the steps ....but don't know where and when to use them??

i asked my teacher about it , and she just said its because the computer stores stuff with  regards to 2's complements for any subtraction...but it still didn't clarify my doubt ...i mean why does it has to do that??

someone please clarify it for me..

Comment: Using complements means that the only operation necessary is addition.

Comment: could you please elaborate your explanation for me???

Comment: and also how do i know when to use it?? that is, whenever i have to subtract do i have to make use of complements? is that what u mean @Peter Smith

Comment: In case someone is scratching her head [here's the Wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements)

Comment: @user1890202 i have already read it... i know how to find the complements... i'm just not understanding why and when to use it?? maybe i'm not looking at the bigger picture ...so help me solve my doubt ...

Comment: @shaistha my comment was meant for those unfamiliar with the subject - as for myself I had only heard of two's compliment. Be patient and one of the gurus might give a clever answer!

Comment: 10's complement works like this, for example: \$\small 472-251=472+749-1000\$. So, form the 10s complement of \$\small 251\$ (\$\small=749\$), add (\$\small =1221\$), and ignore the carry (\$\small =221\$). With binary numbers, 2's complementing is simply changing 1's to 0's and 0's to 1's and, adding 1.

Comment: @Chu yeah i get it you are subtracting with 1000 because u are eliminating the carry....what my question is ...how do u know that you have to use 10's complement rather than 9's complement here??

Comment: 10's complement is 9's complement +1, clearly you need 10's complement to form the composite number that you must add to implement subtraction: (749-1000)=-251

Comment: @Chu please tolerate me...n tell me how can u be so sure that we need 10's complement only to form composite number???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic point is that 2's complement simplifies things because you can use an adder to easily implement subtraction, this is because with 2's complement you have

$$-B = \overline{B} + 1$$

so if you have to perform the operation \$A - B\$ you can easily evaluate it by evaluating \$A + \overline{B} + 1\$.